# Tracking a value for X time

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, event-tracking, time-tracking

How would one go about tracking a value over a rolling time period in Nodejs?

IE:
An event that may return '1' or '0' every 10 sec's,
if this event were to return a '1' every 10's for the last 5 minutes then emit true
but if there was one or more instances of a '0' for the last 5 minutes then emit false

i have done some googling, but just seem to keep getting pointed to the setTimer function, which is not what I'm looking for.

could anyone provide some pointers, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a rare case of your problem where if there is *one* or more instance of 0, we can emit false whenever the event gives a 0:

```js
var place = 0;
var intv = setInterval(() => { 
  if (place > 30){ // 30 * 10 seconds = 5 mins
    console.log("true");
    clearInterval(intv);
  }
  place++;
  if (event() == '0'){
    console.log("false");
    clearInterval(intv);
  }
}, 10000); //10 seconds
```

If it was more than 1 time, for example the problem was 7 or more times, we can use a variable to keep track of the event outcomes:

```js
var instancesOfZero = 0;
var place = 0;
var intv = setInterval(() => {
  if (instancesOfZero == 7) { // 7 is the desired # of instances to emit false
    console.log("false");
    clearInterval(intv);
  }
  if (place > 30){
    console.log("true");
    clearInterval(intv);
  }
  place++;
  if (event() == '0'){
    instancesOfZero++;
  }
}, 10000);
```